# Implementing uniqueness within AFNetworking

Tags: json, design-patterns, unique, afnetworking

I'm trying to design a good architecture for uniqueness within AFNetworking. Consider the situation, for example, where a User can have many Things, and each thing has a symmetric to-one relationship back to its owning User.

The pattern for initializing a User, on login, say, is clear. Create an array of Thing objects out of the parsed data, and set it on the User. (See below.) The analogous 'update' method is similar.

```
**User.m:** 
- (id)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
    // snip. . . .        
    _userID = [[attributes valueForKeyPath:@"id"] integerValue];
    _username = [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"username"];
    _avatarImageURLString = [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"avatar_image.url"];

    NSArray *thingsData = [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"things"];
    NSMutableArray newThings = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *aThing in thingsData) {
        Thing *thing = [[Thing alloc] initWithAttributes:aThing];
        [newThings addObject:thing];
    }

    self.things = [newThings copy];

    return self;
}
```

But what to do with the Things `user` attribute, especially when, for example, fetching a large array of Things that may have pointers to different Users, some the logged-in user, and some to others?

Consider the example code in the AFNetworking project:

```
**Thing.m**
- (id)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
    // Init, etc . . . .    
    _user = [[User alloc] initWithAttributes:[attributes valueForKeyPath:@"user"]];

    return self;
}
```

This code creates scads of dangling User objects and is clearly not the way to go. The best solution would be something akin to what EOF/CoreData does, faulting in the associated object on demand and maintaining a database based on ID. I could duplicate that functionality, but this seems so common a use case that I expect it's done already.

I don't want to use RestKit just for this functionality; it's overkill for this app.

Any suggestions for good patterns? Am I missing some rockin' functionality within AFNetworking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in [AFIncrementalStore](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore).  It's an [NSIncrementalStore](http://nshipster.com/nsincrementalstore/) subclass that links Core Data to AFNetworking, and it's way simpler than [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) (albeit with fewer features.)

Alternatively, you could deal with duplicate user data - you say it's "clearly not the way to go", but it's possible that it wouldn't be a noticeable performance hit if the objects are lightweight enough.  One benefit of this approach is that you could use [NSCoding / NSKeyedArchiver](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) to cache the data - the API is much simpler than Core Data.

Finally, if you like the Core Data approach and want something between AFIncrementalStore and RestKit, consider [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord).  I haven't used it personally, but it's generally well adopted and there exists ample sample code for integrating it with AFNetworking.

Comment: I really want to avoid CoreData entirely. It's just overkill. I did look at MagicalRecord but, while good, it doesn't match the level of AFN. But! Your suggestion that maybe I can get by without iniquity is an interesting one. I have so much data modeling banged into my head that I have a hard time even thinking of it... I'm going to see what else comes out of the brilliant SO, but this bears thought too. Thanks!

Comment: It's less the performance hit than the organizational complexity hit. But I think you've talked me into it! I worry too much... Any other ideas are welcome, but I'm going to go with "don't", and if need be do some dumb local caching/checking. Thanks, both of you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer and the question has nothing to do with networking. It's more a question of *data modeling*.

I suspect, you want to have an app that connects to a web service which provides the data and other services. (Otherwise a network class makes not much sense)

A "uniqueness" property of an attribute will be defined on the database level through using an unique index for the attribute(s). It seems, what you are referring to is more a "relation", a 1:m relation between a user and a number of other objects of type Thing. Web service frameworks usually have convenient ways where you can define the data model in its very details.

In order to create a web service application you can use one of the plenty available and free frameworks. You may look in the web for further information.

You may only want to utilize Core Data in conjunction with a web service, if you want to hold a sub-set of the server data locally on client side. This requires that you also know well how to keep the local data and the data on the server in sync. Unless, you have read-only data - and Core Data works merely as a cache, this task will become quite a challenge.

I can't emphasize enough the last statement: the complexity of synchronization is often underestimated. An unsound and carelessly performed approach without understanding the complex theory behind will likely fail miserably.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, I don't want to use core data, and I'm familiar with the usual patterns (and wrote a couple books on EOF, the predecessor to CoreData. That why I know I don't want to engage it!) I was hoping for a named-and-numbered solution within or around the AFNetworking community, since this is, as you say, a very common data problem.

Comment: community, since this is, as you say, a very common data problem. Thanks for the basic intro to modeling, too. That's not the heart of the problem - I'm just trying to find the lightest weight, ideally extant solution, minimally engineered. I was sure it would exist already! Any other ideas?

Comment: Oops, I said I didn't want to do rest kit, but not CD entirely. Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: Sorry, there is no named and numbered solution in AFN. It's basically a data modeling problem and how you represent the "Model" in the client (say, a "User" class), the transport type (e.g. JSON, XML) and on the server side (Rails ActiveRecord, etc.). That's not the realm of a network library. The network library just performs HTTP requests. Aaron pointed to MagicalRecord which can solve the problem on the client side.

Comment: Uniqueness, and re-establishing it, is a common problem whenever data is transported over a boundary. As a problem it is independent of the transport mechanism or data format. Many people using AFNetworking are working with data services, and many write extensions to it. I was hoping a solution like AFIncrementalStore, but without CD, was available. In the end, I went without modeling it in one case, and decided to bite the CoreData bullet in the other and used RestKit.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, maybe it is better to let the server "re-establish" the associations (via relational database operations and ORM). What you receive on the client side would be an object _user_ which has many _things_. The transport format can be JSON, XML, Yaml, etc.  This implies, you can't get _all_ things as a relation. A RESTful web server would solely transport "objects" (resources) as opposed to relations and methods.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's possible - if the things have a url to the user. ;)   But that depends how the API is designed.